# Visual Studio 2022 How to locate current file in Class View using a shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I can use a short cut to locate the current file in solution explorer, but I can't do the same for Class View.

I don't want to always track the current file open. I want to press a shortcut and see that file in the class view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you are seeking is the shortcut `View.SynchronizeClassView`.  By default this has no shortcut assigned to it.

Go to Tools → Options → Environment → Keyboard and filter the shortcut list by searching for "View.SynchronizeClassView".  Select the item in the list, create a shortcut of your liking, and assign it.

[image: class view shortcut]

After doing so, when you perform the shortcut, class view should sync to where your cursor is at in the code like so:

[image: classview]